# Side-by-side comparison of more than two files containing numerical values

Tags: text-processing, awk, diff

I have three files containing a sorted sequence of numbers, one per line :

**file1**

```
1
2
3
```

**file2**

```
1
3
4
```

**file3**

```
1
5
```

I want to "align" these three files side-by-side like the following :

```
file1  file2  file3
1      1      1
2      
3      3
       4
              5
```

I've tried with `sdiff` but it only works with 2 files

Comment: Do you test `diff3` ?

Comment: @Costas `diff3` doesn't have that output format.

Comment: @Costas Yes, I've tested with `diff3` and as @Kusalananda correctly stated, it doesn't produce that output. Also, I'm looking for a generic solution (for n files, n > 2)

Comment: If you compare line by line why `5` is in the fifth line in result instead third?

Comment: I don't compare line by line

Comment: for this u can write a simple python script. take the number of files as separate lists and then zip them together

Comment: @IjazKhan I don't see how this can achieve what I am looking for, this is not simply zipping 3 Arrays together it should compare them. As you can see in the desired output, there are "blanks" added when a number is missing in a file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could process each file and print a line with some character e.g. `X` for every missing number in the sequence 1-*max* (where *max* is the last number in that file), `paste` the results then replace that character with space:

```
paste \
<(awk 'BEGIN{n=1};{while (n<$1) {print "X";n++}};{n=$1+1};1' file1) \
<(awk 'BEGIN{n=1};{while (n<$1) {print "X";n++}};{n=$1+1};1' file2) \
<(awk 'BEGIN{n=1};{while (n<$1) {print "X";n++}};{n=$1+1};1' file3) \
| tr X ' '
```

If a certain value is missing from all files you'll get empty lines in your output (actually they're not empty, they contain only blanks).
To remove them replace `tr X ' '`  with `sed '/[[:digit:]]/!d;s/X/ /g'`
Also, if you need a header you can always run something like this first:

```
 printf '\t%s' file1 file2 file3 | cut -c2-
```

Comment: I had a hard time figuring out what the `;1` part at the end meant, though. I'm using `{print $0}`instead, a bit less cryptic IMHO. Anyway, thanks again

Answer (score 5):

A general solution with awk: requires GNU awk

```
gawk -v level=0 '
    FNR==1 {level++; head[level]=FILENAME}
    !seen[$1]++ { n++; idx[$1] = n }
    { out[idx[$1]][level] = $1 }
    END {
        for (j=1; j<=level; j++) {
            printf "%s\t", head[j]
        }
        print ""
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            for (j=1; j<=level; j++) {
                printf "%s\t", out[i][j]
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' file{1,2,3,4}
```

```
file1   file2   file3   file4   
1   1   1       
2           2   
3   3           
    4       4   
        5       
            6
```

---

Took a different and simpler approach to this based on Don's comment:

```
gawk '
    FNR==1 { printf "%s\t", FILENAME }
    { seen[$1][FILENAME] = $1 } 
    END {
        print ""
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
        for (i in seen) {
            for (j=1; j<=ARGC; j++) {
                printf "%s\t", seen[i][ARGV[j]]
            } 
            print ""
        }
    }
' file{1,2,3,4}
```

```
file1   file2   file3   file4       
    1   1           
            2       
3   3               
    4       4       
5       5           
            6       
7
```

Comment: Got it. Answer updated

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `bash`, `join`, `paste`, and bad taste:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then exit 1; fi

files=( '' "$@" )

declare -a temps
for ((i=0; i<=$#; i++)); do
    [ $i -eq 0 -o -f "${files[$i]}" ] || exit 1
    temps[$i]=$( mktemp -t "${0##*/}"_$$_XXXXXXXX ) || exit 1
done
trap 'rm -f "${temps[@]}"' EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM

cat "$@" | sort -u >"${temps[0]}"

TAB=$( printf '\t' )
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    join -j1 -a1 -t"$TAB" "${temps[0]}" <(paste "${files[$i]}" "${files[$i]}") | \
        sed "/^[^$TAB]\$/ s/\$/$TAB/" >"${temps[$i]}"
done

printf '%s' ${files[1]}
for ((i=2; i<=$#; i++)); do
    printf '\t%s' ${files[$i]}
    let j=i-1
    let k=i-2
    join -j1 -t"$TAB" "${temps[$j]}" "${temps[$i]}" >"${temps[$k]}"
    cat "${temps[$k]}" >"${temps[$i]}"
done
printf '\n'

cut -d "$TAB" -f 2- <"${temps[$#]}" | sort -n
```

Except for the last `sort -n`, all this works with any text items rather than numbers, as long as the items don't contain tabs (but `TAB` can be changed to any other separator).  Also, it could be done with just 3 temporary files and some shuffling things around (but that would just increase the bad taste).